# For translation of axes, is there a definite equation for any of "the 27 lines" on the Clebsch Diagonal Cubic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coordinate-systems, surfaces, cubics

For the [Clebsch Diagonal Cubic](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClebschDiagonalCubic.html) (related to a [Quanta mag article on Hilbert's 13th Problem](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-resurrect-hilberts-13th-problem-20210114/)), I want to generate a point at will on any of these lines along the surface. Wolfram calls these "Solomon's Seal Lines" but I've had much better luck searching "27 lines on a cubic surface", e.g. [this analysis](https://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2016/02/15/27-lines-on-a-cubic-surface/).

Despite having EngCalc~4, I am a bit overwhelmed by the (graduate-level) technical terms in the topic *(and so...apologies if my terminology is also broken here)*. Are there explicit polynomials for these so I can iterate a point along a line across the surface (or even just hit an Eckardt point)? Page 186 in [The Geometry of Cubic Hypersurfaces](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/Notes.pdf) (PDF author Daniel Huybrechts) is the closest I've gotten to a definition of the lines.

If an application helps, my ultimate goal is to do a passive transformation / translation of axes to have the translated origin follow a line's path, so I can analyze coefficients under the new origin. Here's a (wip) [Desmos 3D graph](https://www.desmos.com/3d/3c26aa111e) where I'm doing an origin translation (all subscript-2 items are passive, where $(h_{2}, i_{2}, j_{2})$ is the new passive origin (in green) and $coe_{2(x,y,z)}$ are the new coefficients for the same surface, but with respect to the new origin).

*EDIT:* In case comments expire: Added [short Desmos 2D explanation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ffctu0hbmc) of iterating a point (the alias origin) along a path, this method upscales to 4D and is what I want to do along the surface. Then I found [how to plot [lines] on Clebsch surface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279405/how-to-plot-clebsch-surface-with-those-27-lines) (mathematica.se), with comments by "bmf" leading to [a possible parameterization](https://analyticphysics.com/Higher%20Dimensions/27%20Lines%20on%20a%20Cubic%20Surface.htm).

*EDIT 2* Via the AnalyticPhysics model, I am able to move the aliased origin along one of the lines by setting (in the Desmos 3D linked above) $j_2 = \frac{1}{3}$ ; $i_2 = (\frac{2}{3} - h_2)$  and then sliding $h_2$ at will. Calculated $d_{istance} = 0$ always (so it stays on the surface) and it appears to be an instance of what I am seeking, but I am not able to write my own answer at this time.

Comment: If you're just looking for the equations of the lines, these are [well-known](https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/clebsch/clebsch.shtml). Or is there something else you're after here?

Comment: @KReiser I like that a lot, but am having trouble converting what's there into a line function I can parameterize to yield a point's coordinate(s) some distance along any line. I'm worried this is beyond my ken, but I'll study it. [edit: Note, I'm using nCr to change coordinates, this may be why I'm lost]

Comment: If you want to know how to convert the equations of a projective line into a parametrized line in some affine chart (eg the line $X_1 + X_2 = X_3 + X_4 = X_5 = 0$ becomes $t \mapsto (t, -t, 1, -1, 0)$ in the chart $X_3 = 1$), then that has little to do with cubic surfaces and should a separate question (or this question should be edited appropriately). As it stands I read this question as asking how to find those equations.

Comment: @ronno Perhaps the problem is that I really am out of my depth (and I go study some more; just found: "Rational Parametrizations of Real Cubic Surfaces" (Bajaj, Holt, and Netravali) looks just like what I'm attempting). I think I'm literally just looking for a polynomial z = f(x,y) ... probably in a cubic form (so three possible z's) but...I can't tell what distinction you're trying to get across to me as to the problem with my question. That's my fault. If I should close this question or something, I can do that.

Comment: I don't mean to dismiss the question or suggest it should be closed. It's just not so clear what exactly you're asking for. There is a question in the title that KReiser's comment addresses at least partially, but what do you mean by explicit polynomials or to iterate a point? A line is one dimensional so it will not have an equation of the form z = f(x, y), but possibly of the form y = f(x), z = g(y).

Comment: @ronno Tentatively, I suspect we agree...writing a [small Desmos 2D](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ffctu0hbmc) with comments to answer "iterate a point". With respect, I worked to keep it not a lot of work for anyone viewing. Ironically on finishing, I found a [mathematica.se question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279405/how-to-plot-clebsch-surface-with-those-27-lines) they wanted closed because it wasn't "math"...leading to a parameterization I think I want. I can't answer, but am willing to accept an answer if I've just somehow made it easy for one to be written.